# Function to change names of variables in R

Tags: r

I have a data set that has a poor naming convention in it and I'm struggling to find a way to automate the name changing process. An example of the data is shown below:

```
x1 <- rnorm(10)
x2 <- rnorm(10)
y  <- rnorm(10)
x11 <- rnorm(10)
x3 <- rnorm(10)
y1 <- rnorm(10)
x21 <- rnorm(10)
x31 <- rnorm(10)

data <- data.frame(x1, x2, y, x11, x3, y1, x21, x31)
head(data,2)
```

This outputs a data frame that looks like this:

```
          x1         x2          y        x11          x3         y1
1 -0.9071106  0.6852567  0.7185932 -0.1943458  1.71832739  0.1568951
2 -0.4592129 -0.3567014 -0.3137624  0.9683101 -0.15601160  0.8513820

         x21        x31
1  0.6160399 -1.3877095
2 -1.0286380 -1.6583842
```

What I'm trying to do is change the name of each x-column to the to the first number that appears beside the x. For example, column x11 should just read x1... and column x21 should be just x2. I could achieve this by manually changing each name by doing something like this:

```
names(data)[startsWith(names(data), "y")] <- "y"
names(data)[startsWith(names(data), "x1")] <- "x1"
names(data)[startsWith(names(data), "x2")] <- "x2"
names(data)[startsWith(names(data), "x3")] <- "x3"

head(data,2)
```

Which outputs:

```
          x1         x2          y         x1         x3         y
1 -0.9071106  0.6852567  0.7185932 -0.1943458  1.7183274 0.1568951
2 -0.4592129 -0.3567014 -0.3137624  0.9683101 -0.1560116 0.8513820
          x2        x3
1  0.6160399 -1.387709
2 -1.0286380 -1.658384
```

But I'm struggling to write a function to do this over the entire dataset. Also, I realise that this will result in having multiple x1, x2 (etc) columns... but for my purposes, I need the data like this.

Any suggestions as to how id write this function?

Comment: Might be easier with RegEx and/or `rename_at` but some people prefer sticking with `base`. Also better not to use `data` as a variable name.

Comment: Could you just take the first two characters? `names(data) <- substr(names(data),1,2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `sub` to capture the letteer followed by the digit as a group  and replace with the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
names(data) <- sub("^([xy]\\d)\\d$", "\\1", names(data))
names(data)
#[1] "x1" "x2" "y"  "x1" "x3" "y1" "x2" "x3"
```

Or by removing the last digit that follows a digit

```
sub("(?<=\\d)(\\d)$", "", names(data), perl = TRUE)
```

If it is a `data.frame`, it wouldn't support duplicate column names as there would be checks with `make.unique`.  But, if it is a `matrix`, it can have duplicate column name

---

Another option if we are creating with `data.frame` call is to use `check.names = FALSE`

```
data <- data.frame(x1, x2, y, x1 = x11, x3, y1, x2 = x21,
         x3 = x31, check.names = FALSE)
```

But, it is not recommended to have duplicate column names as this can lead to trouble in extracting the columns with column names

Comment: Thanks, I know it's not advised to have duplicate col names. But unfortunately, for what I'm doing. I need them. Otherwise, thank you... your suggestion worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

We can use a regex to capture an optional first character followed by a digit.

```
names(data) <- sub("(.?\\d).*", "\\1", names(data))
names(data)
#[1] "x1" "x2" "y"  "x1" "x3" "y1" "x2" "x3"
```

which can be achieved with `str_extract` by

```
names(data) <- stringr::str_extract(names(data), ".?\\d?")
```